# RESTful semantics for different mechanisms

Tags: rest

Imagine I am creating an API to allow a user to attach an image to their profile, where the image may come from a binary submission in the body, or a url, which the server will retrieve and process.

Assuming the API expects a PUT with binary image data to

```
/user/jon/image
```

When adding the URl functionality, which of the following would be preferable?

```
A:
PUT to /user/jon/image/url
passing the url in the body
```

or

```
B:
PUT /user/jon/image/
passing in a url in the body and setting a MIME type to advise the host whether or not the content is an image or an URL?
```

Is there a standard way of dealing with this situation?  I feel that using MIME types to dictate the payload is more semantically correct, but a little less discoverable

Thanks

Comment: What is your question

Comment: Amended - I am wondering what is the best scheme to allow an API to get the same information from different sources.  I'm kinda stumped for a terse title for the question

Comment: Are you going to retrieve the image from the url or just use the image at the stated location?

Comment: Good point - the url will be retrieved by the server and processed.  Once the image is submitted in wither form, the user should be able to perform a GET /user/jon/image to see their image

Answer (score 0):

Once I had this same problem. I solved it by first posting the image by "PUT /user/jon/image/" and then posting the URL with PUT to /user/jon/image/url.

The problem is, that the user posts an image and forgets about the URL. I solved this by saving the image temporally in a session and when the URL is posted, I saved the URL and the image at the same time.

Problem is, this is not Restful, because a restful server doesn't have sesions. But being 100% restful is almost imposible, so its your choice.